# How to run a progress bar asynchronously while performing silent installs?

Tags: powershell, asynchronous, progress

## The Goal:

I want to asynchronously run a progress bar (which shows elapsed time/estimated time) while waiting for silent installs. For instance,

```
RunWithProgressBar "cmd /c """" /Wait ""Setup.exe""" $(New-Timespan -Minutes 5)
```

## Closest I've Come:

```
## Functions

function global:BottleOfBeer {
  $beer = $args[0]
  if ($beer -eq 1) {
    echo "$beer beer on the wall.";
  } elseif ($beer -eq 0) {
    echo "No beer left on the wall!";
  } else {
    echo "$beer beers left on the wall.";
  }
  sleep 1
}

function global:BeersOnTheWall {
  $NumBeers = $args[0]
  for ($i=$NumBeers; $i -ge 0; $i--) {
    BottleOfBeer $i
  }
}

function global:Install {
    cmd /c @"
        "AutoHotkey112306_Install.exe" /S /D="%cd%"
"@
}

function global:Uninstall {
    cmd /c start "" /wait "Installer.ahk" /Uninstall
}

####START Progress Bar Stuff
function global:DisplayProgress {
  $display = $args[0]
  Write-Progress    -Activity "Running..." -Status "$display"
}

function global:FormatDisplay {
  $StartTime = $args[0]
  $RunningTime = ($args[1]).Elapsed
  $EstimatedTime = $args[2]
  $RunningTimeDisplay = $([string]::Format("{0:d2}:{1:d2}:{2:d2}",
    $RunningTime.hours, 
    $RunningTime.minutes, 
    $RunningTime.seconds))
  $EstimatedEnd = $StartTime + $EstimatedTime
  return $([string]::Format("(Start: {0}) (Elapsed/Estimated: {1}/{2}) (EstimatedEnd: {3})",
    $StartTime.ToShortTimeString(), 
    $RunningTimeDisplay, 
    $EstimatedTime,
    $EstimatedEnd.ToShortTimeString()))
}

function global:TearDownProgressBar {
  $job = $args[0]
  $event = $args[1]
  $job,$event | Stop-Job -PassThru | Remove-Job #stop the job and event listener
  Write-Progress -Activity "Working..." -Completed -Status "All done."
}

function RunWithProgressBar {
  $Payload = $args[0]
  $EstimatedTime = $args[1]

  $global:StartTime = Get-Date
  $global:RunningTime = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
  $global:EstimatedTime = $EstimatedTime

  $progressTask = {
    while($true) {
      Register-EngineEvent -SourceIdentifier MyNewMessage -Forward
      $null = New-Event -SourceIdentifier MyNewMessage -MessageData "Pingback from job."
      Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    }
  }

  $job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock $progressTask
  $event = Register-EngineEvent -SourceIdentifier MyNewMessage -Action {
    DisplayProgress $(FormatDisplay $global:StartTime $global:RunningTime $global:EstimatedTime)
  }

  try {
    sleep 1
    Invoke-Expression $Payload
  } finally {
    TearDownProgressBar $job $event
  }
}
####END Progress Bar Stuff

## MAIN

RunWithProgressBar "BeersOnTheWall 2"  $(New-Timespan -Seconds 3)
RunWithProgressBar "Install"  $(New-Timespan -Seconds 30)
RunWithProgressBar "Uninstall"  $(New-Timespan -Seconds 5)
RunWithProgressBar "BeersOnTheWall 2"  $(New-Timespan -Seconds 3)
```

## The Problem

Although the above implementation runs as intended, whenever the payload argument of `RunWithProgressBar` is an install the event which updates the progress bar stops getting triggered.

## What I'm Looking For:

How to modify my current implementation to update the progress bar every second, even while performing an install?

Comment: By what measure would you want the progress bar to update? The system can't look into the future to see when an installation would be finished, nor does it know which items the installer is going to process.

Comment: You make a judgement call as a human based on how long you think it will take. Ex. Notepadd++ should install within 5 minutes. This script will be run on multiple machines of the same type; reasonable estimates are easy to find from the first run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the solution provided earned the bounty, it's not what I ended up doing. Here's the final version of RunWithProgressBar():

```
param ( 
    [alias("IM")]
    [bool]$IgnoreMain = $false
)

function RunAsBAT([string]$commands) {
    # Write commands to bat file
    $tempFile = $global:scriptDir + '\TemporaryBatFile.bat'
    $commands = "@echo off `n" + $commands
    Out-File -InputObject $commands -FilePath $tempFile -Encoding ascii
    # Wait for bat file to run
    & $tempFile
    # Delete bat file
    Remove-Item -Path $tempFile
}

function DisplayProgress([string]$display) {
    Write-Progress  -Activity "Running..." -Status "$display"
}

function FormatDisplay([System.DateTime]$StartTime, [System.TimeSpan]$RunningTime, [System.TimeSpan]$EstimatedTime) {
    $RunningTimeDisplay = $([string]::Format("{0:d2}:{1:d2}:{2:d2}",
        $RunningTime.hours, 
        $RunningTime.minutes, 
        $RunningTime.seconds))
    $EstimatedEnd = $StartTime + $EstimatedTime
    return $([string]::Format("(Start: {0}) (Elapsed/Estimated: {1}/{2}) (EstimatedEnd: {3})",
        $StartTime.ToShortTimeString(), 
        $RunningTimeDisplay, 
        $EstimatedTime,
        $EstimatedEnd.ToShortTimeString()))
}

function RunWithProgressBar([scriptblock]$payload, [System.TimeSpan]$EstimatedTime) {
    $global:StartTime = Get-Date
    $global:RunningTime = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
    $global:EstimatedTime = $EstimatedTime

    try {
        $logFile = $global:scriptDir + '\TemporaryLogFile.txt'
        $StartInfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo -Property @{
                        FileName = 'Powershell'
                        # load this script but don't run MAIN (to expose functions/variables); 
                        # run the payload (and also log to file);
                        # if error, pause (so the window stays open to display the error)
                        Arguments = ". $global:scriptPath -IM 1; & $payload | Tee-Object -file $logFile;" + ' if ( $LastExitCode -ne 0 ) { cmd /c pause }'
                        UseShellExecute = $true
                    }
        $Process = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
        $Process.StartInfo = $StartInfo
        [void]$Process.Start()

        do
        {
            DisplayProgress $(FormatDisplay $global:StartTime ($global:RunningTime).Elapsed $global:EstimatedTime)
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
        }
        while (!$Process.HasExited)

    }
    finally {
        if (Test-Path $logFile) {
            Get-Content -Path $logFile
            Remove-Item -Path $logFile
        } else {
            Write-Host "No output was logged..."
        }
        Write-Progress  -Activity "Working..." -Completed -Status "All done."
    }
}

function TestBlockingCall {
    RunAsBAT(@"
        timeout 5
"@)
}

## MAIN

if (-Not $IgnoreMain) {
    RunWithProgressBar { TestBlockingCall } $(New-Timespan -Seconds 7)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I feel like you are trying to *reinvent the wheel* in your `RunWithProgressBar` function:

```
 $progressTask = {
    while($true) {
      Register-EngineEvent -SourceIdentifier MyNewMessage -Forward
      $null = New-Event -SourceIdentifier MyNewMessage -MessageData "Pingback from job."
      Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    }
  }

  $job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock $progressTask
  $event = Register-EngineEvent -SourceIdentifier MyNewMessage -Action {
    DisplayProgress $(FormatDisplay $global:StartTime $global:RunningTime $global:EstimatedTime)
  }
```

This is basically a **timer** and can be refactored:

```
$timer = new-object timers.timer     
$action = {DisplayProgress $(FormatDisplay $global:StartTime $global:RunningTime $global:EstimatedTime)} 
$timer.Interval = 1000 
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $timer -EventName elapsed –SourceIdentifier thetimer -Action $action | out-null
$timer.Start()
```

However, to solve your problem, you could *execute the task in a job* and wait until they finish.

Instead of making the functions public, consider *define them in a* `scriptblock`:

```
$initializationScriptBlock = {
    $functions = @{        
        Install = {
            cmd /c '"AutoHotkey112306_Install.exe" /S /D="%cd%"'
        }

        BottleOfBeer = {
          $beer = $args[0]
          if ($beer -eq 1) {
            echo "$beer beer on the wall.";
          } elseif ($beer -eq 0) {
            echo "No beer left on the wall!";
          } else {
            echo "$beer beers left on the wall.";
          }
          sleep 1
        }

        BeersOnTheWall = {
            $NumBeers = $args[0]
            for ($i=$NumBeers; $i -ge 0; $i--) 
            {
                BottleOfBeer $i
            }
        }

        Uninstall =  {
            cmd /c start "" /wait "Installer.ahk" /Uninstall
        }
    }
}
```

Now, intead of `Invoke-Expression $Payload` you start a new job by passing the `initializationScriptBlock` and the actual function `$functionToExecute` as the  `scriptblock` to execute:

```
$executingJob =  start-Job -InitializationScript $initializationScriptBlock -ScriptBlock $functionToExecute 
while ((Get-job $executingJob.Id).State -eq 'Running')
{
    sleep 1;
}
```

Your `RunWithProgressBar` function now using `PowerShell`-like function definition:

```
function RunWithProgressBar 
{
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
        [scriptblock]$functionToExecute,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1)]
        [timespan]$EstimatedTime
    )
....
}
```

Please consider to also change the rest of the script for *readability*.

To invoke a function with a progressbar, you first have to load the `initializationScriptBlock`
to the current runspace:

```
. $initializationScriptBlock
```

Now you are able to invoke the functions like this:

```
RunWithProgressBar $functions.BottleOfBeer (New-Timespan -Seconds 3)
RunWithProgressBar $functions.Install (New-Timespan -Seconds 30)
```

Your whole script now looks like this:

```
## Functions
$initializationScriptBlock = {
    $functions = @{

        Install = {
        Sleep 5
        <#cmd /c @"
        "AutoHotkey112306_Install.exe" /S /D="%cd%"
"@#>
        }

        BottleOfBeer = {
          $beer = $args[0]
          if ($beer -eq 1) {
            echo "$beer beer on the wall.";
          } elseif ($beer -eq 0) {
            echo "No beer left on the wall!";
          } else {
            echo "$beer beers left on the wall.";
          }
          sleep 1
        }

        BeersOnTheWall = {
            $NumBeers = $args[0]
            for ($i=$NumBeers; $i -ge 0; $i--) 
            {
                BottleOfBeer $i
            }
        }

        Uninstall =  {
            cmd /c start "" /wait "Installer.ahk" /Uninstall
        }

    }

}

####START Progress Bar Stuff
function global:DisplayProgress {
  $display = $args[0]
  Write-Progress    -Activity "Running..." -Status "$display"
}

function global:FormatDisplay {
  $StartTime = $args[0]
  $RunningTime = ($args[1]).Elapsed
  $EstimatedTime = $args[2]
  $RunningTimeDisplay = $([string]::Format("{0:d2}:{1:d2}:{2:d2}",
    $RunningTime.hours, 
    $RunningTime.minutes, 
    $RunningTime.seconds))
  $EstimatedEnd = $StartTime + $EstimatedTime
  return $([string]::Format("(Start: {0}) (Elapsed/Estimated: {1}/{2}) (EstimatedEnd: {3})",
    $StartTime.ToShortTimeString(), 
    $RunningTimeDisplay, 
    $EstimatedTime,
    $EstimatedEnd.ToShortTimeString()))
}


function RunWithProgressBar 
{
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
        [scriptblock]$functionToExecute,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1)]
        [timespan]$EstimatedTime
    )

  $global:StartTime = Get-Date
  $global:RunningTime = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
  $global:EstimatedTime = $EstimatedTime


  $timer = new-object timers.timer 

    $action = {DisplayProgress $(FormatDisplay $global:StartTime $global:RunningTime $global:EstimatedTime)} 
    $timer.Interval = 1000  

    Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $timer -EventName elapsed –SourceIdentifier thetimer -Action $action | out-null

    $timer.Start()

  try {
    $executingJob =  start-Job -InitializationScript $initializationScriptBlock -ScriptBlock $functionToExecute
    while ((Get-job $executingJob.Id).State -eq 'Running')
    {
        sleep 1;
    }

  } finally {
    $timer.stop() 

    Unregister-Event thetimer
  }
}
####END Progress Bar Stuff

## MAIN
. $initializationScriptBlock

RunWithProgressBar $functions.BottleOfBeer (New-Timespan -Seconds 3)
RunWithProgressBar $functions.Install (New-Timespan -Seconds 30)
RunWithProgressBar $functions.Uninstall (New-Timespan -Seconds 5)
RunWithProgressBar $functions.BeersOnTheWall (New-Timespan -Seconds 3)
```

Your script should work now even there are *still a lot to refactor* e. g. function names, scopes

**Answer to your comment:**

1.) You can use [Receive-Job](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113372) inside your loop to retrieve the output:

```
$executingJob =  start-Job -InitializationScript $initializationScriptBlock -ScriptBlock $functionToExecute
while ((Get-job $executingJob.Id).State -eq 'Running')
{
    Receive-Job $executingJob.Id
    sleep 1;
}
Receive-Job $executingJob.Id
```

2.)
After you executed the `$initializationScriptBlock` using:

```
. $initializationScriptBlock
```

You can use any functions:

```
& $functions.BottleOfBeer
```

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for (but helpful). 2 problems: 1) How can the above be modified to show job output while the job's ongoing? Is that even possible? 2) Is there any way to use functions outside of (or wrap them in) the initializationscriptblock functions property?