# Using async and await that updates data in real time

Tags: wpf, powershell, async-await

I have tried the code mentioned in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27089652/

It works fine and I want to use it for running a PowerShell script in for loop. GUI was freezing initially then I tried the code mentioned in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35735760/

Now GUI does not freeze while the PowerShell script is running in the background although nothing is updated in the textbox until for loop is complete. I want to see the results updating in real time. Here is the code I am running:

```cs
        private async void run_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Text1.Text = "";
            
            await Task.Run(() => PS_Execution(Text1));

        }

        internal async Task PS_Execution(TextBox text)
        {

            PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
            ps.AddScript(script.ToString());

            {

                Collection<PSObject> results = ps.Invoke();
                foreach (PSObject r in results)
                {
                    text.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                    {
                        text.Text += r.ToString();
                    });
                    await Task.Delay(100);
                }                
            }
        }
```

Maybe I am missing something important. Please help me understand how to solve this problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Write PowerShell Output (as it happens) to WPF UI Control](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36716964/1701026) or simply use `Start-Job` as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37376311/1701026)

Comment: The most important thing you are missing is your ignorance of the main way that UI elements receive data: Bindings to Data Context Properties.
If text.Text had been assigned a binding, then no Dispatcher call would be required.
It would be sufficient to change the value of the Bind source property.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using `ps.Invoke()` which is synchronous call and will wait for all results to return use `ps.BeginInvoke()` instead.  Then subscribe to the `DataAdded` event of the output PSDataCollection and use the action to update your ui.

```
private async void run_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Text1.Text = "";
    await Task.Run(() => PS_Execution(Text1));
}


internal async Task PS_Execution(TextBox text)
{
    using PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
    ps.AddScript(script.ToString());

    PSDataCollection<string> input = null;
    PSDataCollection<string> output = new();
    IAsyncResult asyncResult = ps.BeginInvoke(input, output);

    output.DataAdded += (sender, args) =>
    {
        var data = sender as PSDataCollection<string>;
        text.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            text.Text += data[args.Index];
        });

    };
}
```